# Why can't I change custom view background in cell of UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` and a custom `UICollectionViewCell`.
The `UICollectionViewCell` contains a custom `UIView`.

I need to change the color of the UIView according to a property in my array.

I have created the custom `UIView` in the storyboard, assigned appropriate class to it and even a tag.

I am trying to change the color of the my custom circleView in cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("circleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BRGameCollectionViewCell
    var circle = BRGameManager.sharedInstance.gameArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as BRCircle!

    cell.circleView.circleColor = UIColor.redColor()

    return cell
}
```

I have tried it even with getting the `circleView` via `tag` but it doesn't work either.

What Am I doing wrong?

My custom view Class looks like this:

```
class BRCircleView: UIView {

    var circleSize : CGFloat = 10
    var circleColor : UIColor!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        if( frame == CGRectZero){
            var newFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.circleSize, self.circleSize)
        }

        self.circleColor = UIColor(rgba: GlobalConstants.colors.hexColorGreen)

        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    convenience init(frame: CGRect, circleColor : UIColor){
        self.init(frame: frame)

        self.circleColor = circleColor
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width/2
        self.clipsToBounds = true

        self.backgroundColor = self.circleColor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reflect your `circleView`'s background color change,you need to redraw your view's content.Use `setNeedsDisplay` method of `UIView` would do this trick.[More about setNeedsDisplay](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay)

So before returning cell, add this line of code.

```
...

cell.circleView.circleColor = UIColor.redColor()

cell.circleView.setNeedsDisplay() // add this line.

return cell
```